# datetime conversion - TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, typeerror

I have such a dataframe:

```
ds  y
22/02/18 13 1
28/07/19 14 1
09/02/21 15 2
```

I want to get column ds to datetime and use:

```
df1['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['ds'], format = '%d/%m/%y %H')
```

But get:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

What do I have to do here? The problem is, the exact same operation worked before but now it is not possible anymore.

Edit: Thanks for all the answers! I found an error in my script which likely leaded to the error. Please, vote for a close of the question.

Comment: Could you put a better version of your dataframe? It is not really clear where the elements of each column start and end. Which is the content of your column "ds" and which is the content of the column "y"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the data time is in a 'string' format the conversion works just fine. So maybe convert it to string format first?

```
data = {'ds':['22/02/18 13', '28/07/19 14', '09/02/21 15']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df1['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['ds'], format = '%d/%m/%y %H')
df1
```

Out:

```
ds
0   2018-02-22 13:00:00
1   2019-07-28 14:00:00
2   2021-02-09 15:00:00
```

Hope this may help?